# TouchableOpacity not working on ios

Tags: reactjs, native, react-native

I have the following code:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
disabled={!this.state.canGoBack} 
onPress={this.onBack.bind(this)}>
<Icon 
   name="arrow-back" 
   style={this.state.canGoBack ? styles.iconStyleActive :
   styles.iconStyle}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This works perfectly fine on Android. However, on iOS my app fails to load. I don't get any errors and activity indicator just keeps spinning.
I tried without TouchableOpacity and the icons load fine.

Edit: Seems to also work if i replace Icons with Text then the touchable opacity works.

RN version: "react-native": "^0.45.1",

Comment: react-native version ?

Comment: Did you wrote the Icon component yourself? If so, could you post the code for it?

Comment: No it's native-base, i have also tried other icon packages with same results.

Comment: Have you tried adding a size to the Icon?

Comment: You might not be able to use that icon for ios, you might have to change it to `name="ios-arrow-back"` or something like that.

Comment: Yes, tried all ios specific icons - same result and also applied styles to them.
Recreated the app from scratch and copied code over and same result.

Comment: It seems like you have to  use `react-native-vector-icons`. Have you installed fonts into ios project?

Answer (score 1):

Issue seems resolved after deleting Node Modules folder and clearing cache.
This seemed to have been a temporary fix, same issue occured when app was launched again without any changes to the code.

Comment: Just close Iphone simulator, metro then run again and fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Just seen One more thing in Native Base and Found

They are using the ions according to Platfrom

```
<Icon ios='ios-menu' android="md-menu" style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'red'}}/>
```

May be this can Help you

Answer (score 0):

It depends more on Icon styling. If you put Height/width const or set absolute position then TouchableOpacity is sometimes ineffective.

Try using flex and min max with height width.